# Instagram / iOS app - Post an image choosing the account

Tags: ios, instagram

I'm building an app where you can post an image to Instagram. I'd like to support multiple accounts.

Is there a way to specify the account when posting the image?

I'm currently using iOS sharing action sheet, but I can use any other mechanism to post to Instagram. I just need to find one that works with multiple accounts.